# zip files and download using php

Tags: php, zip

I have a question

I have looked all over stacked overflow, on how to make a zip out of multiple files, and I got this code:

```
    <?php
        $data = $_POST['data'];
        $zip = new ZipArchive();
        $zip_name = dirname(__FILE__)."/billeder.zip"; // Zip name
        $zip->open($zip_name,  ZipArchive::CREATE);

        foreach ($data as $file) {
            $path = dirname(__FILE__)."/".$file;
            $zip->addFromString(basename($path),  file_get_contents($path));  
        }

        $zip->close();

        header('Content-Type: application/zip');
        header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($zip_name));
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zip_name));
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        readfile($zip_name);
        unlink($zip_name);
    ?>
```

the post data look something like this:

```
["Billede_008.JPG","Billede_011.JPG"]
```

a list of images.

My problem is that, I don't receive the zip file, when posting to the url.
I have checked that it got the post data, I've checked that all files in the post exists, and I have checked that the files were added to the zip.

[image: here is the response data from chrome] 
here is the response from chrome. as you can see there's nothing wrong with the response, but I still don't get the zip.

Can anyone see, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `filesize($zip_name)` leads to `Content-Length: 38` doesnt look as your zip file were properly generated

Comment: btw, chrome lets you easily copy/paste the headers. Properly formatted text would be nicer than screenshots

Comment: Have you tried [ZipArchive::addFile](http://php.net/manual/de/ziparchive.addfile.php) instead of `addFromString()`?

Comment: @simon.ro But why doesn't it generate the zip correctly? I've followed every guide there is.

Comment: @simon.ro I've just tried that, now it says the content-length is 2

Comment: maybe you should check `file_exists($path)` and `is_readable($path)` before adding the files

Comment: @simon.ro All files surpases the check: file_exists && is_readable

Comment: the funny part is when I send a get request without any parameters I get the zip file, just without any files in it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148249/discussion-between-simon-ro-and-tomas0206).